# Woocommerce: append atribute value to order-notes

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to append the atribute value of pa-lager to delieverynotes and invoices. I'm working from [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49630369)

This is what I have:

```
function lager_placering( $product ) {
 if( isset( $product->id ) ) {
$lager = $product->get_attribute('pa_lager');
//echo $lager;
}
}

add_action( 'wcdn_order_item_after', 'lager_placering' );
```

It does not work. at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works like a charm

```
function lager_placering( $product ) {
$lager = $product->get_attribute('pa_lager');
echo $lager;
}
add_action( 'wcdn_order_item_after', 'lager_placering' );
```